# I’m unable to install scipy in pycharm - Metadata Generation Failef

Tags: python, installation, scipy, pycharm, metadata

I keep getting metadata generation failed errors when trying to install scipy to pycharm.  I’m using the latest versions of python and scipy.  I have entered exclusions in Windows Defender for all my Python and pycharm folders. I turned off the private firewall. I updated pip, setuptools, etc. I have also tried adding “prefer binary” and cacheless downloads.

I’ve had similar problems downloading other packages like matplotlib, but usually going with a prefer binary download would fix it. Not so in this case.

Scipy ver is 1.11.3 and Python ver is 3.11.6.

The errors read: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toll) … error

There’s also a WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files\ … \vswhere.exe

Also, a number of exceptions with running icl cl cc gcc clang clang-cl and pic

I am new to python and am out of ideas. Any insights?

See original post

“I keep getting metadata generation failed errors when trying to install scipy to pycharm.  I’m using the latest versions of python and scipy.  I have entered exclusions in Windows Defender for all my Python and pycharm folders. I turned off the private firewall. I updated pip, setuptools, etc. I have also tried adding “prefer binary” and cacheless downloads.

I’ve had similar problems downloading other packages like matplotlib, but usually going with a prefer binary download would fix it. Not so in this case.”

Comment: `python -m pip install scipy`

Comment: and here is te link...  https://scipy.org/install